# maven: Unable to run junit5-jupiter-starter-maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

I downloaded the current version of the JUnit 5 sample code from https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/r5.2.0/ and extracted the subfolder [junit5-jupiter-starter-maven](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/r5.2.0/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven) to a local temp folder.

Then I openend a console window and tried to run that sample with `mvnw clean test`, but all I got was an **`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/core/LauncherFactory`**

Full maven output (of re-run without downloads):

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building junit5-vanilla-maven 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ junit5-vanilla-maven ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\temp\junit5-jupiter-starter-maven\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ junit5-vanilla-maven ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ junit5-vanilla-maven ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\temp\junit5-jupiter-starter-maven\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ junit5-vanilla-maven ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ junit5-vanilla-maven ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.245 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-01T16:31:25+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/306M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project junit5-vanilla-maven: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\temp\junit5-jupiter-starter-maven\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/core/LauncherFactory
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/core/LauncherFactory
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:658)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:122)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:50)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

`mvnw --version`:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T21:39:06+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\<XXX>\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\6ps54u5pnnbbpr6ds9rppcc7iv\apache-maven-3.5.0
Java version: 1.8.0_171, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre
Default locale: de_AT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Did I do something wrong, or can you reproduce this problem?

Comment: Running fine for me. Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-04T03:39:06+08:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\xxx\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\6ps54u5pnnbbpr6ds9rppcc7iv\apache-maven-3.5.0
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the error is

`[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/core/LauncherFactory`

I suggest to check the `junit-platform-launcher` jar file. Maybe it is corrupted.

It should be the one of`\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-launcher\1.2.0\junit-platform-launcher-1.2.0.jar`

Comment: yes. thanks. that was it. still need to get used to that maven thingy. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For my it was a different problem. Multimodule maven project has two modules A and B, where A is using `junit-pioneer:1.9.1` (having transitive dependency from `junit-platform-launcher:1.8.2`) when module B doesn't use `junit-pioneer` but fails to build because of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/core/LauncherFactory` when building the whole project with `mvn clean install`.

My solution was to add (unused) test dependency from `junit-pioneer` to module B.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update maven-surefire-plugin to v3.0.0, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1679.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```